# Determine if input keyEvent added or removed something

Tags: jquery, events, input, onkeyup

Suppose I am catching a keyup event with jQuery on an input field. Now I am doing various things with the event, for example reacting to the tab or enter key. Now I want to determine if a key like tab, control, alt, shift was pressed or a key that actually alters the input like letters, numbers, punctuation etc.

Is there any way to determine this? How do I make sure to check all the right keys any user anywhere could press?

I hope my problem is clear.

### Edit 1:

Well, I was a little fast there with closing the question. There is still a problem. My solution so far ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LHtnt/)):

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
    var lastValue = '';
    if(typeof $(this).attr('data-last-value') != 'undefined' && $(this).attr('data-last-value') != '') {
        lastValue = $(this).attr('data-last-value');
    }

    if(lastValue != $(this).val()) {
        //This is what I wanted.
    }

    $(this).attr('data-last-value', $(this).val());
});
```

Problem: If the user for example entered 'hello' into the input, then selects the 'h' and presses the h-key, the script does not recognize it as one of the desired key presses, because the value was not altered. IS there any way around this behavior?

Comment: Could you provide a working fiddle with problem you described? It's a little bit difficult to understand what you want

Comment: I added the Fiddle. The problem: I want the condition to be true if the user pressed a key to edit the content (for example letters, punctuation, backspace etc) but not when pressing other keys (for example alt, shift, left, right, tab etc). How do I distinguish between these two types of keys?

Comment: Why do you need to keep track of letters being pressed if input did not change? If you really need to keep track of that I think you will need to check all the possible keyCodes that are not letters and do check for them.

Comment: In my particular case, the user expects the focus to jump to the next input field as soon as a valid value is entered. Sometimes this is only a single letter. So if they for example by pressing tab focus on an input containing a single letter, they might press that letter again and expect to be send to the next input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one of possible solutions would be to save length of input before altering the input and on some event check the new lengh i.e.:

```
var inputsLength = {};

$(window).keydown(function (e){
  var input = e.eventTarget,
      name = input.name,
      oldLength = inputsLength[name];

  if (!oldLength) {
    inputsLength[name] = input.length
  }

  if (oldLength !== input.length) {
    //something change
  } else {
    //everything is the same
  }

  if (e.ctrlKey) alert("control");
});
```

Alternative solution for your updated question would be to use "input" event which captures only what you really want in this situation.

```
$(window).on('input', function(e) {
    //Do what you need
});
```

P.S. have in mind that this does not work IE < 9 and is a little buggy in IE 9. But for your needs I think it should be a good fit

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I slightly modified it to store the old value of the input, not only the length in order to catch replacing letters. Now it works like a charm!

Comment: Sorry, I was a little fast with accepting this. I edited the question, because there still is a problem with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In short, KeyCodes.

```
$('element').keyup(function (e) {
    var event = e || window.event; //for firefox mainly
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13:
            //do something here (keycode 13 is enter)
            break;
        //continue for all keycodes you are checking for
    }

    //alternatively
    var modKeys = [69, 70, 71]; //ect... (keys which will modify the input)
    var otherKeys = [9, 13, 16]; // ect... (keys which wont)

    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, modKeys)) {
        //code for modification key
    } else if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, otherKeys)) {
        //code for non-modification keys
    }
});
```

EDIT:
For a list of keycodes: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).keydown(function (e){
    if (e.ctrlKey) alert("control");
});
```

The list of modifier keys:

```
e.ctrlKey
e.altKey
e.shiftKey
```

Comment: Yes, but what about for example the NumKey, up, down, left, right, and so on and so on. There are so many keys to watch out for. How can I catch all keys that do not directly contribute to the content of the input?

Comment: Look at the ascii table and see what ranges of keys you can and cannot accept.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" id="txtboxToFilter" />

(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtboxToFilter").keyu[(function(event) {

        if (event.ctrlKey == true)
            alert("control key pressed");
        //or you can do something like this also using key codes
        if (event.keyCode == 9)
            alert("tab key pressed");

        }

    });
});
```

[JavaScript Key Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: My problem is: it is close to impossible to check for all the possible keys on all keyboard layouts.